# Gnome terminal causes separate icon in launcher

Tags: icons, gnome-terminal, 16.10

As of 16.10 (I think), starting Gnome Terminal causes a new icon to appear in the launcher, with a dot next to it. Starting another instance causes another dot to appear.

[image: screenshot]

How can I prevent this behaviour?

I remember seeing Chrome do this, and you had to manually edit its `.desktop` file to avoid a second icon. Would something similar work for Gnome Terminal? I'm using version 3.20.2.

Answer (score 1):

This happens to be quite often (I often reinstall different versions of gnome-terminal). I don't know the cause of the issue, but I just simply remove the old icon (the one without the "dots") and lock the new one to the launcher.

Comment: Even better: after removing the "old"  icon the new one is *already* locked to the launcher. +1 for this workaround.